# Prolog simple backtracking

Tags: prolog

I want to create a predicate "move" in prolog that takes three arguments: A, B, Number. If Number is 1, predicate should add 1 to A, if Number is 2, function should add 1 to B. Then predicate checks whether A==B, if no, it should rerun with new values. So it should look similar to this:

```
check_eq(First, Second) :-
First == Second.

move(A, B, Number) :-
integer(Number),
Number <= 2,
(Number == 1 ->
    C is A+1,
    (check_eq(C, B) ->
        true
    ;
        move(C, B, X)
    )
;
    C is B+1,
    (check_eq(A, C) ->
        true
    ;
        random(1, 2, X),
        move(A, C, X)
    )
).
```

Of course this doesn't work. What I want to do is write a command like move(1, 5, X) and (using a backtracking) get true, because it is possible to reach A==B after some operations. But what should I change in code to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
move(A, B, 1) :-
    B =:= A+1,
    !,
    format("Success with (~d,~d,~d)~n",[A,B,1]).

move(A, B, 1) :-
    B =\= A+1,
    !,
    random_between(1, 2, X),
    C is A+1,
    format("Not done with (~d,~d,~d), continuing with (~d,~d,~d)~n",[A,B,1,C,B,X]),
    move(C, B, X).
   
move(A, B, 2) :-
    A =:= B+1,
    !,
    format("Success with (~d,~d,~d)~n",[A,B,2]).
        
move(A, B, 2) :-
    A =\= B+1,
    random_between(1, 2, X),
    C is B+1,
    format("Not done with (~d,~d,~d), continuing with (~d,~d,~d)~n",[A,B,2,A,C,X]),
    move(A, C, X).
```